# Is extern "C" turning C code to C++ code, or just allowing the compiler to compile C code as C++ code?

Tags: c++, c

I have a small issue.

I thought that using using `extern "C"` will turn the C code into C++ code directly.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES CAN_Send_Message(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[], uint8_t delay);
ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES CAN_Send_Request(uint32_t ID, uint8_t PGN[], uint8_t delay);
bool CAN_Read_Message(uint32_t *ID, uint8_t data[]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

But when I placed a class `QSerialPort` in here

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <QSerialPort>
ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES CAN_Send_Message(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[], uint8_t delay);
ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES CAN_Send_Request(uint32_t ID, uint8_t PGN[], uint8_t delay);
bool CAN_Read_Message(uint32_t *ID, uint8_t data[]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then I got 500 errors about data types, name space and all kind of C++ keywords that C does not have.

**Question:**

In QT. I have to make sure that I can use a C++ class inside a `.h` file and the `.h` is included inside a `.c` file. But right now, my QT IDE shows me 500 errors if I do that.

Is there a way for C code to call C++ code or turning the C code into 100% C++ code, whithout renaming the files `.c` to `.cpp`?

My goal is to use C++ features from C, by using `extern "C"` inside the header of the `.c` file, but it isin't going any well for me.

**Edit:**

I tried some ways and this does not work. I get 500 errors.

```
#include <QSerialPort>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void QT_USB_set_serial_handler(QSerialPort* serial_port);
ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES QT_USB_Transmit(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[], uint8_t DLC);
void QT_USB_Get_ID_Data(uint32_t *ID, uint8_t data[], bool* is_new_message);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

This gives only one error.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <QSerialPort>
extern "C" {
#endif

void QT_USB_set_serial_handler(QSerialPort* serial_port); <-- complaining here on QSerialPort keyword
ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES QT_USB_Transmit(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[], uint8_t DLC);
void QT_USB_Get_ID_Data(uint32_t *ID, uint8_t data[], bool* is_new_message);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

This gives no error at all.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <QSerialPort>
void QT_USB_set_serial_handler(QSerialPort* serial_port);
extern "C" {
#endif

ENUM_J1939_STATUS_CODES QT_USB_Transmit(uint32_t ID, uint8_t data[], uint8_t DLC);
void QT_USB_Get_ID_Data(uint32_t *ID, uint8_t data[], bool* is_new_message);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
```

Comment: It's forcing C++ to generate identifiers usable by C code. [Helpful reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)

Comment: It is straightforward to call C code from a program that's predominantly written in C++.  It is *not* straightforward (personally I believe it's generally impossible) to call C++ code from a program that's predominantly written in C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `extern "C" { ... }` in C++ code, around *declarations* of *external functions* which are C functions, not C++ functions.

`extern "C" { ... }` does *not* somehow "turn C code into C++ code".
It does not turn C++ code into C code, either.

You use `extern "C" { ... }` when you have some other function(s) to call, and those other functions are present in source files ending in `.c` and compiled as C, not C++.  `extern "C" { ... }` makes sure that your C++ compiler passes arguments, generates function calls, emits relocation information, etc., in a way that's compatible with C, not C++.

There's no mechanism (that I know of) to embed arbitrary C code inside a C++ source file, and have it treated as C.  And there's even less of a mechanism to embed arbitrary C++ code inside a C source file, and have it treated as C++!

---

Addendum: I'm somewhat embarrassed that this answer has been upvoted and accepted, since I've just realized it's been only partially correct so far.  `extern "C"` can indeed be used to mark an external function (defined elsewhere) as being named and called using C conventions, as I said.  But it can also be used to mark a C++ function (defined "here") as being named and called using C conventions, so that it can be called from a C function elsewhere.

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c/1041880#1041880) for a better explanation of this.

To summarize, I believe there are two almost completely different cases using `extern "C"`:

| syntax | function defined | function written in | function called from | caller written in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| function declaration | somewhere else | C (or maybe C++) | here | C++ |
| function definition | here | C++ | somewhere else | C or C++ |

In particular, you can call a C function from C++ (first row, the case I was talking about above), but you can also call a C++ function from C (second row, that I tend to forget is even possible).  In the second case, when you're calling a C++ function from C, I think you have to make sure that your final compilation uses a C++ compiler, not a C compiler, so that the right run-time support will be provided for the C++ functions that need it.

Comment: Yes. I'm using extern "C" correctly, but I think I need another solution if I want to use C++ features inside the C code.

Comment: But imagine.... `extern "Pascal" { (* Pascal code goes here *) }`, and `extern "BASIC" { REM Basic code goes here }` and `extern "FORTRAN" { C FORTRAN code goes here }` and `extern "Brainf" { +[-->-[>>+>-----<<]<--<---]>-.>>>+.>>..+++[.>]<<<<.+++.------.<<-.>>>>+. }` ... the pain is endless!

Comment: _I want to use C++ features inside the C code._ Then wrap them in free functions, declared as `extern "C"`.

Comment: @PaulSanders You mean between `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `#endif` ?

Comment: Yes, if you're going to include the same header file in both C and C++ source files (which would be the recommended way).

Comment: @MrYui "*I want to use C++ features inside the C code*" - that will never work, since a C compiler is not a C++ compiler. But what you can do instead is put the C++ code into an external DLL library that exports the necessary functionality as C-style functions that are wrapped in `extern "C"`. Then the C code can use those DLL functions as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for that suggestion. I don't know how to create a DLL file. But I think I solved it above in my edited question.